# Error in SerialPort Closes Thread but don't change it's Status and don't raise an Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, serial-port

I am reading a `SerialPort` in a separate thread using the code below.

I open the `Serial Port` and try to `read a line`. Since there is nothing connected in the `Serial Port` there is an error. I was expecting some `TimeoutException` to be thrown, but NO! There are not Exceptions being thrown and the Task stops working!

As far as I know, a [Task can be shutdown by returning from it, or throwing an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this code doesn't do either. The task stops working and the Task Status remais as `WaitingForActivation`.

What's going on? I need to handle this kind of error in my application but I can't see any kind of Exception or error being reported by the `SerialPort`.

Also I tried to go into Tools/Options/Debugging and turn off "Enable Just My code (Managed only)" and this didn't do anything.

The code is:
(I placed it inside a button click to make it easier to replicate.)
(In order to run this you need a FTDI cable or something like it, and nothing connected to the cable).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name != "Main")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Started from thread '{0}'.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name));
        TestTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "TestTask";
                int i = 0;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Started from thread '{0}'.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name));
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM14"); 
                        while (!serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Open(); // Try to open the SerialPort.
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("From Thread '{0}', Try to read now:", Thread.CurrentThread.Name));
                        string s = serialPort.ReadLine(); // here's the error.
                        i++; // this line is never executed.
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("From Thread '{0}', Loop Count : {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, i));
                    }                        
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                            
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        while(true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("From Thread '{0}', TestTask Status: {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, TestTask.Status));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        //try // I tried this before the 'while(true)' above to see if there were any Exceptions being thrown to the "outside" but no, nothing here.
        //{
        //    TestTask.Wait();
        //}
        //catch(AggregateException ae)
        //{
        //    ae.Flatten();
        //}
    }
```

An output of the program is like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: By 'exception not thrown' do you mean the exception gets in the scope but  VS Debugger does not 'break'? (unless you toggle a bp in the catch scope) or MessageBox.Show() does not show the messagebox?

Comment: If I place a breakpoint, it does not break, if I place a MessageBox it isn't shown, the while loop doesn't continue and the task status keeps at WaitingForActivation

Comment: It is not closed, and it has not stopped working.  It is doing exactly what you told it to do.  When a line of input comes in through the port, it will capture it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this issue might vary depending on what modules interact with the serial port.

However, there are a few things you need to go over to get what you expect from the code.

First of all, the `TestTask` is always *waiting for activation* as long as `while(true)` is there for infinite loop.

Second, `SerialPort.Readline` does not throw `TimeOutException` and wait until a line is received, [unless you set the `ReadTimeout` propety to a non-zero value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

`try-catch` for exception in `Task.Run` has to work as it should.
You can see it work in this **extremely simple code** example as follows:

```
var TestTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }                        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                            
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, you will still want to check how your VS debugger behaves when encountering any exceptions by looking at `Debug - Exception...(Ctrl+Alt+E)`, in which its option columns can be different depending on whether *Just My Code* is enabled or not, in case you are confused. (I personally prefer to have it enabled).

If you want to catch all the exceptions your application throw no matter whether it'll be properly handled in the future or not, check *Thrown* column in that option window.
That will cause VS debugger to break every time an exception is thrown.

Comment: Failure to configure timeouts is the most likely problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree too. :-)

Comment: Yeah....it blocks since there is no timeout....I could only find this now on the method online documentation, but not on the code comment documentation.... I will answer my question with this.

Comment: @mFeinstein If the timeout property is the answer to your question, you can mark mine as answer. It's clearly stated at the second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this will be right, although I appreciate a lot your help, your answer only explains that a `TimeoutException` only happens if there is a Timeout configured.... But the real answer is that the `ReadLine()` blocks forever since there is a not a newline character in the stream and no Timeout configured. I explained this and quoted the documentation. The rest of your answer actually speaks of stuffs that I had already explained in my question, like looking for Just My Code, and the Task status. If you elaborate more on your answer, I will for sure mark it as the answer

Comment: My point is, the answer is about the method blocking, as it's default behavior, and a timeout defined if the user dont't want it to block, if your answer explains this, I will mark it as correct for sure.

Comment: "SerialPort.Readline does not throw TimeOutException and *wait until a line is received,*" with the whole next line linking to the official documentation is what you just described.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77677/discussion-between-dean-seo-and-mfeinstein).

Answer (score 0):

The Thread was locked inside the `ReadLine()` method because there was no `ReadTimeout` defined. The Thread as indeed still executing and no errors or Exceptions were interfering with it.

I was just not expecting the method to block since the code documentation didn't specify that the method will block indefinitely, until a newline character is received. But the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes it clear:

> By default, the **ReadLine method will block until a line is received**. If this behavior is undesirable, set the ReadTimeout property to any non-zero value to force the ReadLine method to throw a TimeoutException if a line is not available on the port.